# A good single word or shorter phrase for "ascending numbers with no gaps"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a good word/phrase for that concept? By ascending with no gaps, I mean something like:

> 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

In other words, every number after the first, *n<sub>0</sub>*, can be defined as *n<sub>x</sub> = n<sub>x-1</sub> + 1, x > 0*.

Obviously there are gaps before the first and after the last but I don't care about those.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better answered on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the example in the question, I'm assuming that "ascending numbers with no gaps" refers to whole numbers (or integers).

So the term you're after would be **[consecutive integers](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutive_integer)**. That is, a sequence of whole numbers that follow each other in order with a difference of 1 between every two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**Consecutive**:

> following one after another in a continuous series
>
> [[Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/consecutive?q=consecutive)]
> Web. Accessed 5/26/2021.

In math, [consecutive] numbers follow each other continuously in the order from smallest to largest.  You can also use "sequence," since in math 1,2,3,4,5 is a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

"Consecutive integers in ascending order", if you need to make it clear that they are in the order 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 rather than any other order. Or "consecutive integers going upwards", say.